# Shrink before wrapping a list of buttons

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a list of buttons in a flex container. Here is the [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/aekrn6g9/).

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: grey;
  padding: 10px;
}


.btn-container {
  min-width: 50px;
  display: flex;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}


.container>button {
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.btn-container button {
  min-width: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="btn-container">
  <Button>
    hello world
  </Button>
  <Button>
    hello hello hello world
  </Button>
  <Button>
    hello hello hello world
  </Button>
  <Button>
    hello hello hello world
  </Button>
  </div>
  <button>
    Button adder
  </button>
</div>
```

I am trying to make the buttons shrink first displaying ellipses then collapse after making the screen smaller in width.

In the example, The buttons shrink only. When I add `flex-wrap: wrap` to `.btn-container` they only wrap without shrinking. So how can I make them shrink before wrapping?

Note: When wrapping, I need the buttons to not grow more than their actual width.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approximate this using `flex-basis:0` combined with `flex-grow`. I also rely on `max-width: max-content;` to limit the grow effect:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: grey;
  padding: 10px;
}

.btn-container {
  min-width: 50px;
  display: flex;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container>button {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.btn-container button {
  min-width: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  flex-basis:0;
  flex-grow:1;
  max-width: max-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="btn-container">
    <Button>
    hello world
  </Button>
    <Button>
    hello hello hello world
  </Button>
    <Button>
    hello hello hello world
  </Button>
    <Button>
    hello hello hello world
  </Button>
  </div>
  <button>
    Button adder
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, This does not work for me because when it wraps, the buttons fill the whole flex space. I want the buttons to have max-content width and not stretch

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks a lot. Very smart answer. I was missing the max-content thing.

Comment: Please not that for ellipsis to work an element needs to have a 'limiting'  width factor like width/max-width and, as in this case, `flex-basis: 0; max-width: max-content`. @isherwood, essentially those two are key. As said before `min-width` only forces the `wrap` when out of space....